# How to remove an inherited field from a new content type

Tags: content-type, plone, archetypes

I'm working with ArgoUML/AGX/Plone 4.1 to generate a subclass using "atevent" as the stereotype. How do I remove the inherited "Event body text" field?

Comment: By subclass I assume you mean your own event type? Are you asking how to remove it with Argo/AGX or just in general? Please explain what you have tried before asking this question. E.g. reading the docs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the widget invisible for editing and for viewing.

```
YourSchema['FieldName'].widget.visible = {'view': 'hidden', 'edit':'hidden' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field is required in the original schema, you'll also need

```
YourSchema['FieldName'].required = False
```