# Remove description field on new content type

Tags: plone

I have made a new content type BASED on ATFolder, but noticed that this includes a description field. 
Is there a way to remove this, or at least just remove it from the edit page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted at [How to remove an inherited field from a new content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459045/how-to-remove-an-inherited-field-from-a-new-content-type): you can set the widget invisible for editing and for viewing.

```
YourSchema['FieldName'].widget.visible = {'view': 'hidden', 'edit':'hidden' }
```

and If the field is required in the original schema, you'll also need

```
YourSchema['FieldName'].required = False
```